# Change DateTime month -> " list[i].date.Month = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); "

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to change the month and the day of a DateTime in a list

This is the class:

```
public string NomeCliente { get => nomeCliente; set => nomeCliente = value; }
public int Hora { get => hora; set => hora = value; }
public int Minutos { get => minutos; set => minutos = value; }
public DateTime Data { get => data; set => data = value; }
public int Campo { get => campo; set => campo = value; }
```

And this is my code:

```
Console.Clear();
Console.Write("Novo nome cliente: ");
listaMarcacoes[pos].NomeCliente = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Insira o horário:");
Console.Write("\tHora: ");
listaMarcacoes[pos].Hora = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("\tMinutos: ");
listaMarcacoes[pos].Minutos = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Insira o mês: ");
listaMarcacoes[pos].Data.Month = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Insira o dia: ");
listaMarcacoes[pos].Data.Day = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Insira o campo: ");
listaMarcacoes[pos].Campo = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

The error is happening with the "`listaMarcacoes[pos].Data.Month = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`" and "`listaMarcacoes[pos].Data.Day = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are the errors exactly? What did you put on your console as an input? What is `listaMarcacoes` exactly? Can you create a [MCVE] that demonstrate your problem? Have you ever tried to debug your code? I really wanna suggest to you read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times before you ask more questions.

Comment: [The property only has a setter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.day?view=netframework-4.8) - you can't change it.  You have to create a new `DateTime` (or preferrably, `DateTimeOffset`) object and assign that to your `Data` field.

Comment: _Datetime.Month_ and _Datetime.Day_ are readonly properties - you cannot assign values to them

Comment: If you have an answer, please use the Your Answer box below to answer your question. Don't add the answer to your question or edit "Solved" into the title. Thank you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow, I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

As @Clockwork-Muse said, I have to create a new DateTime, so basically what I had to do was save the month and day on a new variable and then send it to the new DateTime.

Like this:

```
listaMarcacoes[pos].Data = new DateTime(var year, var month, var day);
```

Answer (score 0):

always validate the user input before assign it.

For instance take this line :

```
Console.Write("\tMinutos: ");
listaMarcacoes[pos].Minutos = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

if the user input is anything other than digits, it'll throw an exception immediately.

to avoid that, you'll need to first store the value, then validate it like this :

```
var minutes = Console.ReadLine(); 
int _minutes = 0;

if(int.TryParse(minutes, out _minutes))
{
    listaMarcacoes[pos].Minutos = _minutes;
}
else 
{
    Console.Write("is not an integer, please make sure you enter numbers only.");
}
```

Now, you can go further and expand your logic based on the user input, and will be better handled.

for instance, since it's minutes, we assume the input range will be between 0 to 60
then we can do this :

```
if(int.TryParse(minutes, out _minutes))
{
    if(_minutes >= 0 && _minutes <= 60)
    {
        listaMarcacoes[pos].Minutos = _minutes; 
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.Write("please choose a number between 0 and 60.");
    }
}
else 
{
    Console.Write("is not an integer, please make sure you enter numbers only.");
}
```

For the date, you need to initiate a new instance of Data, you can initiate it from the class model like this :

```
public DateTime Data { get; set; } = new DateTime();
```

this will create a new instance once the class is initiated. Or simply initiated at the beginning of your code.

```
Data = new DateTime();
```

then you can do this :

```
listaMarcacoes[pos].Data.Month = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Wow thank you :) I did forgot to check values and was ready to show the demo to the client, seems like I have to check some things on my code. Thanks for that! (I can't upvote but if I could I would)